# i am making mp3 player using c# but i am sufferring from this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]"

Tags: c#

i am making mp3 player using c# but i am sufferring from this error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]".

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    string[] f, p;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            f = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
            p = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(f[i]);

            }
            foreach(string d in open.FileNames)
            { 
                listBox1.Items.Add(d);
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = p[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Why have you declared `f` and `p` as being `string[]` to start with?

Comment: Errors come from specific lines of code.  Which line of code caused the error?

Comment: I like the way we are left to guess which line has the error :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to handle the user opening multiple files. In that case, use [`FileDialog.FileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx) instead of `FileName`. Ditto [`SafeFileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilenames.aspx).

(I would also strongly recommend renaming the variables so their names are meaningful - `f` and `p` don't tell you anything about them.)

Comment: As an extension to the renaming of the variables - I would also rename your controls to something more meaningful. listbox1 doesn't tell you anything about it and get's problematic the moment you have more than one listbox. Also you define a new OpenFileDialog called open and the proceed to use a different instance - presumably one you have dragged onto the designer judging by it's name.

Answer (score 2):

```
 change your code with following code :---

 f = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
 p = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
```